# How to change output of a layer in a pre-trained CNN model in Keras?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am running VGG16 in Keras for image classification as follows:

```
model = VGG16()
image = load_img('mug.jpg', target_size=(224, 224))
image = img_to_array(image)
image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2]))
image = preprocess_input(image)
yhat = model.predict(image)
label = decode_predictions(that)
label = label[0][0]

# print the output
print('%s (%.2f%%)' % (label[1], label[2]*100))
```

Now I want to view the output of the first layer and change it/add noise to it and see how the classification changes. I am not sure how to do this and could not find any suitable resources that matched my query.

I am new to Keras, so any help on this aspect will be highly appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: adding layers at the end of the model's layers is okay, but I think adding layers in the middle would reduce the model's accuracy. after all, you're harming the model's integrity in a way, and it needs to be re-trained. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes that should affect the accuracy.

Answer (score 3):

The output of any layer can be obtained by

```
model.layers[index].output
```

so in your case you can do

```
outputlayer1 = model.layers[0].output
outputlayer1 += noise
```

later to do a forward pass, you can iterate over the layers and do a forward pass. For forward pass refer to call function in this link https://keras.io/api/layers/base_layer/

Comment: That's okay when I use my own model and train it from scratch. But my question is for pre-trained models.

Comment: isnt a pretrained model also an instance of the same class ? I guess after initializating the pretrained model, you should be able do access its elements and functions in the same way you would do with your own model. Or am I missing something

Comment: That is correct but I want to insert the noise after the first layer and see it's impact on inference. Basically the noisy output of the first layer will serve as an input for the next layer and so on. So you'll have to make the changes when the model is trying to predict or during inference which I'm not sure how to do. I don't see a way other than inserting a noisy layer in the pre-trained model and store it as  a new model.